# Check if input field is empty in the angularjs script

Tags: angularjs-scope

I have a html code, how can i check if the input field is empty in the script. Is there any way we can use scope to check this. I know we have form validation in angular but am just curious.

Comment: Could you please share sample code which you have tried ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve expected result, you can use ng-keyup function

HTML:

```
<html lang="en">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="formCtrl">
  <form>
    First Name: <input type="text" ng-keyup="check()" ng-model="firstname">
  </form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('formCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.check= function(){
      var x =$scope.firstname;
      if(x.length==''){
        alert("input empty");
      }
    };
});
```

Codepen- http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/qNPJZV

Comment: Hello, check() gets triggered every time the input is made empty? Am asking this because, i want check() to be called when the form loads

Comment: And can i use check() for multiple input tag?

Comment: yes you can use it multiple input fields  and updated codepen which works for both on input and on form load ..Hope this works for you :)

Comment: hello, i checked and it works. And we can call same check() for multiple input tags.

Comment: i think that should be different question :)

Comment: Can we use this for select tag also?

Comment: yes we can use for select but instead of keyup , you should use onchange